# Распарсить строку в PHP

Tags: php, json

Есть такой вот кусок кода:

```
($mediaId = '1278763660642187302_215594189';

$dannie = (json_encode($i->mediaInfo($mediaId)));
var_dump($dannie);)
```

Который возвращает мне:
`string(4520) "{"auto_load_more_enabled":true,"items":[{"taken_at":1466660529,"pk":1.2787636606422e+18,"id":"1278763660642187302_215594189","device_timestamp":1466660289,"media_type":1,"code":"BG_FMYwQXgm","client_cache_key":"MTI3ODc2MzY2MDY0MjE4NzMwMg==.2","filter_type":114,"image_versions2"` итд.
Нужно из всего этого получить `id` и занести его в переменную, бился с этим всю ночь, пробовал использовать регулярные выражения, но все равно не выходит.

**Обновление**

Вот что написано в функции, которую мы вызываем:

```
public function mediaInfo($mediaId)
{
    $data = json_encode([
        '_uuid'      => $this->uuid,
        '_uid'       => $this->username_id,
        '_csrftoken' => $this->token,
        'media_id'   => $mediaId,
    ]);


      return $this->request("media/$mediaId/info/", $this->generateSignature($data))[1];
  }
)
```

Вот так мы обращаемся к ней:

```
var_dump($i ->mediaInfo($mediaId));
```

В таком случае мы получаем следующее:

```
array(5) { ["auto_load_more_enabled"]=> bool(true) ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(23) { ["taken_at"]=> int(1466660529) ["pk"]=> float(1.2787636606422E+18) ["id"]=> string(29) "1278763660642187302_215594189" ["device_timestamp"]=> int(1466660289) ["media_type"]=> int(1) ["code"]=> string(11) "BG_FMYwQXgm" ["client_cache_key"]=> string(30) "MTI3ODc2MzY2MDY0MjE4NzMwMg==.2" ["filter_type"]=> int(114) ["image_versions2"]=> array(1) { ["candidates"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(150)
```

P.S С помощью вашего кода получил в итоге NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте json_decode

```
$data = json_decode($text, true);
$id = $data['items'][0]['id'];
```

Скорее всего, $data['items'] - массив с несколькими элементами. Тогда для каждого можно получить id с помощью `foreach ($data['items'] as $item) { echo $item['id']; }`
И не понятно, с какой целью используется json_encode. Почему не работать сразу с полученным объектом?

Answer (score -4):

Вот что написано в функции, которую мы вызываем:
          public function mediaInfo($mediaId)
  {
       $data = json_encode([
        '_uuid'      => $this->uuid,
        '_uid'       => $this->username_id,
        '_csrftoken' => $this->token,
        'media_id'   => $mediaId,
    ]);

```
  return $this->request("media/$mediaId/info/", $this->generateSignature($data))[1];
```

}
)
Вот так мы обращаемся к ней: var_dump($i ->mediaInfo($mediaId));
В таком случае мы получаем следующее:array(5) { ["auto_load_more_enabled"]=> bool(true) ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(23) { ["taken_at"]=> int(1466660529) ["pk"]=> float(1.2787636606422E+18) ["id"]=> string(29) "1278763660642187302_215594189" ["device_timestamp"]=> int(1466660289) ["media_type"]=> int(1) ["code"]=> string(11) "BG_FMYwQXgm" ["client_cache_key"]=> string(30) "MTI3ODc2MzY2MDY0MjE4NzMwMg==.2" ["filter_type"]=> int(114) ["image_versions2"]=> array(1) { ["candidates"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(3) { ["url"]=> string(150)
P.S С помощью вашего кода получил в итоге NULL.

Comment: И что? В чем заключается ответ на вопрос?